# Is there any debug/diagnostic mutex class to help diagnose of multithreading programs?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

I know there are different variants of mutexes C++ classes (standard C++11, Boost, others),
I wonder if is there some kind of debug/diagnostic mutex that could help diagnose aspects of multithreading programming, i.e.:
 - understand if a mutex is really needed (or a null_mutex or nothing at all can be used)
 - understand if a mutex is called recursively (so std::recursive_mutex should be used instead of std::mutex)
 - ... other useful stuff?

Could such a mutex be a good or bad idea, anyway?

Comment: This is a nice question, but it's offtopic because it's a software/library recommendation request.

Comment: Can anyone suggest which SE community may be better on topic?

Comment: As it's closed as "off-topic - recommend me a library" you could give it a try on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Besides, have a look at Valgrind/Helgrind. Haven't used it, but it claims to be made for detecting errors in multithreaded code: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html